# Deleted Migration Files and Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sqlite, heroku

I asked about this once already, but I didn't get a working response, and I may have a better way of asking this question.

Long story short, I've deleted some problematic migration files, (the problem is coming from out-of-order migration files; there is an add_column_to_stocks before a create_stocks file), but for whatever reason, heroku continues to want to migrate these old, deleted files. I have no idea where these files are being stored.

If I do a heroku `db:migrate:status`, this is the response:

```
Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20171231042756  Create articles
   up     20171231044214  Add description to articles
   up     20180116183526  Create users
   up     20180116191414  Add user to articles
   up     20180116195212  Add password digest to users
   up     20180305082108  Create categories
   up     20180305090315  Create article categories
  down    20180515064500  Add latest price to stocks
  down    20180517202216  Add timetables to stock
  down    20180517205823  Add updatedtime to stocks
  down    20180521021514  Create user stocks
```

The problems start at the first down file.

My local migration folder looks more like this:

```
20171231042756  Create articles
20171231044214  Add description to articles
20180116183526  Create users
20180116191414  Add user to articles
20180116195212  Add password digest to users
20180305082108  Create categories
20180305090315  Create article categories
20180515064499  Create stocks.rb
20180521021514  Create user stocks.rb
```

No matter what changes I make to my local migration files, it continues to want to migrate these problematic files, so I always get back the response:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "stocks" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "stocks" ADD "latest_price" decimal
```

I tried getting into the heroku psql console and deleting them manually, but a `delete from schema_migrations where version = 20180515064500` brings back a `DELETE 0` response, meaning it hasn't deleted anything.

I'm friggen stumped and I've spent about a week and a half beating my head in over this.

Thank you all in advance!! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you tried dropping & re-creating database ? `rails db:drop` then rails db:create & migrate

Comment: `git rm db/migrate/20180515064500*.rb` and deploy on heroku.

Comment: Also can you update the question with result of `ls -t db/migrate`

Comment: Sikandar Tariq, will a rails db:drop, create and migrate delete all data on my application?

Comment: @kiddorails, what does the `ls -t db/migrate` command do? I can't seem to find good documentation on it.

Comment: After a little trial and error, your answer @kiddorails was what fixed my problem. It was a simple git rm and migrate changes to heroku. 

Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JoeyMousepad great. I have posted that as answer. If it fixed your problem, you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

File with migration number `20180515064500` should be gone as it is attempting to modify the table which doens't exist.

Remove the files which are breaking the migrations:

```
git rm db/migrate/20180515064500*.rb
```

and deploy on heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Look if in your db files, your version of rails is indicated there (5.2 for example):
In your files that are in down mode.

```
class CurrencyCreateUsers <ActiveRecord :: Migration [5.2]
```

then rake db: migrate